# Getting the count of result respect to a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My

```
select distinct c.*
from kuponbahis c
join bahis b on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID=c.bahis AND c.durum=0
```

Query is giving the result as;

[image: coupon]

How can I get the count of results respect to their "kupon" field.

Expected result;

```
32, 3
33, 2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you really using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group data by `kupon` and use count function to get the count of particular `kupon`

```
select c.kupon,count(*) as count
from kuponbahis c
join bahis b on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID=c.bahis AND c.durum=0
group by c.kupon
```

Comment: Sadly, this returned zero result.

Comment: In which table you have `kupon` column ?

Comment: @Ece: Please check data in both table you are joining

Comment: @Ece: It may be that you don't have matching data in one of the table you are joining .

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. And also there is one question I want to ask, too. Can I make this bahis column specific? Only get same results with related to given **bahis column**
Like;
`select c.kupon,count(*) as count
from kuponbahis c
join bahis b on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID=c.bahis AND c.durum=0 AND **c.bahis=24**
group by c.kupon`

so it will return same results but now it wont get any more result not contains bahis=24

Comment: select kuponbahis.kupon,count(kuponbahis.id) as count
from kuponbahis 
join bahis  on bahis.sonuc = kuponbahis.secim and bahis.ID=c.bahis AND kuponbahis.durum=0  AND kuponbahis.bahis =24
group by kuponbahis.kupon

Comment: Yes you can make it  `bahis` column  specific. For this you have to add where condition just after the `group by` like : `where  bahis =24`

Comment: This gives 32:1, 33:1 result. It needs to give same result.

Comment: See kupon:32 has 3 rows with 3 different bahis columns. What I mean is I need a "if it has bahis=24 in kupon", work, condition.

Comment: If it has  `bahis=24` then what to do with count?

Comment: I need to get kuponbahis counts (same results) with if they have 24 in their bahis column

Comment: Sorry for tiring you btw. :|

Comment: @Ece, so only the `kupon` that has a `bahis=24` will be included in the results set. But the count should count all `bahis`?

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/a2ENoB.jpg in this example it needs to give 32,3-33,1 result but not 34,1 because 34 doesn't contain bahis 24 (it only contains 26 but others are containing 24)

Answer (score 1):

You need use group by:

```
select kupon, count(c.id)
from kuponbahis c
join bahis b on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID=c.bahis AND c.durum=0
group by 1
```

Also your origin query looks strange. You use `JOIN` (wich means `INNER JOIN`) and don't select any fields from joined table. In this case you can get zero results if your second table has no records to be joined. Maybe you should just remove `JOIN` statement?

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I fix my answer. Check it

Comment: why group by 1. it will return only one row with count of all rows.

Comment: No,`group by 1` means group by firs field

Comment: @Ece I think your query has some problems. Why you use `JOIN` if you don't select any fields from table bahis?

Comment: @Evgeny: where is firs  field

Comment: @Code-Monk `group by 1` means `group by` the first column in the `select`. This would be `kupon`.

Comment: @Code-Monk `group by 1` in this case means `group by kupon`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you requirement correctly, you want to count the number of `bahis`, but only include rows that has `bahis = 24`. If so, you can use `COUNT` and filter the results in the `HAVING` clause

```
select c.kupon, count(*) as count
from kuponbahis c
join bahis b 
    on b.sonuc = c.secim 
    and b.ID = c.bahis 
where
    c.durum = 0
group by c.kupon
having count(case when c.bahis = 24 then 1 end) > 0
```